# Unity2D Custom Animated Sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

Really, the question says it all. How can I go about making my own 2d sprites that are animated and use them in unity?

I've used the Standard Assets package from unity on the asset store, but I want to make them myself (the sprites and animations)

Are there any good tools for this and if it's something like blender are there any tutorials? It needs to be free.

Thanks in advance!

PS. It must be 2d sprites.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. If you want pixel art, [Piskel](http://www.piskelapp.com) is a fairly robust free sprite creator. It automatically puts your sprites on an alpha program, and allows you to automatically create sprite sheets, and preview animations. However, if you want something more detailed, some sort of other more advanced program would be advised, such as Paint or Photoshop.